"Introductory Discrete Mathematics" by V.K. Balakrishnan Potential Error in Definition of Comparison Property
I was reading through Chapter 0 of this book where the author is talking about relations on a set and the types of relations (reflexive, transitive, symmetric, etc.).
He then states that "a relation $R$ on a set $A$ has the comparison property (a term I find nowhere else) if either $a R b$ or $b R a$ for all $a,b \in A$". He then goes on to give an example and says that for $A = \{a,b,c\}$ that relation R = $\{(a,c), (b,b), (c,c), (a,b), (c,b)\}$ contains the comparison property. Surely this is false, as $(a,a) \notin R$, which leads me to believe that he meant to say "for all distinct $a,b \in A$" in his definition.
It seems he meant for "the comparison property" to just be what other people call a connected relation, but as it stands, he has defined a strongly connected relation (which is connected and reflexive).
At this point I am confused whether the definition or the example is correct, please let me know what he means by the comparison property (is it a connected relation like in his example or a strongly connected relation as defined?).

The usual term is connected and usually it is stated with $a \ne b$. If so, the example is corerct.

To me, it seems that you are correct in that he wanted "for all distinct $a,b$...", so it just means that the relation is connected. A partial order is reflexive, so you do not need it to be strongly connected as well, just connected, for it to be a total order.

@SomeCallMeTim Ah, you are correct. The whole bottom paragraph of my post can be eliminated then since bringing up his definition of a total order is correct if you interpret the comparison property to just mean the relation is connected.
